# LINQ Entities build Query at Runtime 'The parameter is not in scope.' LinqKit

Tags: c#, linq, linqkit

I'm using LinqKit (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

**Is there a way to have the following code work without having to define a concrete class?**

Trying to build a strongly typed dynamic query with LINQ to Entities.

I'm getting `The parameter 'o' is not in scope.` error.

in certain situations.

```
void Main()
{   
    var lquery = from a in Foo select new { Bar = a.Baz }; // <-- error like this
    //var lquery = from a in Foo select new stuff { Bar = a.Baz }; // <-- here no error
    test("Case", lquery, o => o.Bar).Dump();
}

class stuff { public string Bar {get; set;} }

IQueryable<T> test<T>(string val, IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector){
    var ex = selector.Expand();
    var b = from c in qry.AsExpandable()
            where ex.Invoke(c).Contains(val)
            select c;
    return b;
}
```

It appears that when an anonymous class is used with `test()` this error is thrown when a concrete class `stuff` is used then no error. Is there a workaround which would allow an anonymous class to be used in this situation?

I realize that this error might be LinkKit related but I don't have enough technical knowledge to dive in there...

Comment: How is `Foo` defined? Also, with the code in the question I'm not able to repro, the type arguments cannot be deduced for the call to `test` from `Main`.

Comment: This code can be used with **LinqPad** `Foo` can be replaced with a table name `Baz` can be replaced with a column in said table. I'm running code in **LinqPad** works ok, need a reference to LinqKit.dll and `System.Linq.Expressions` and `LinqKit` namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, I managed to repro in LinqPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **LinqKit** I added a check for anonymous class to ExpressionExpander.VisitMemberAccess() to get anonymous classes to work.

relpaced

```
if (m.Member.DeclaringType.Name.StartsWith ("<>"))
    return TransformExpr (m);
```

with

```
string typeName = m.Member.DeclaringType.Name;
bool isAnonymous = typeName.StartsWith("<>f__AnonymousType"),
     isOuter = !isAnonymous && typeName.StartsWith("<>");
if (isOuter)
    return TransformExpr (m);
```